# Broken comments section - Wordpress 2014 Theme

Tags: comments, theme-twenty-fourteen

I recently switched my Wordpress theme to the "default" 2014 one. Everything looks great, except I'm having trouble with comments showing up correctly. Can somebody help me understand what's wrong?

See http://gregloesch.com/997/notes-from-eloquent-ruby/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was an issue with the minification of some things on my site. Disabling/clearing the cache seemed to have solved the issue.